# Configure MySQL with EFcore 3.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I just started with [Authentication and authorization for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0) of Dotnet core 3.0 by using

`dotnet new angular -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual`

and it created a new project with Angular as a client side app and ASP.net core as a backend. Now I want to use MySQL with this template.

I have tried using two providers for this

1. [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore)
2. [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)

but both of them are not supported with Entityframework core 3.0 and asking me to downgrade to Entityframework core 2.2. When I downgraded to Entityframework core 2.2 another package named [Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/) starts breaking as it requires Entityframework core version 3.0 and above.

Can somebody please tell me how to setup this template of Authentication and Authorization for SPAs for MySQL?

Comment: It seems like Pomelo is just a few days away from having a 3.0-compatible version (but still in development): https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/818

Comment: You can find this step by step video configure .net core 3.0 authenticated web app with mysql here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4I0DUw6C84

Comment: That worked perfectly @navule, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out I had to wait some time for Pomelo Entity Framework Team to release the .NET Core 3.0 Supported version which is [available now](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/3.0.0-rc1.final). All the other things are now working as expected.